# MFCC Feature Extractor

Tags: .net, ml.net, scisharp

I'm looking for a Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficient (MFCC) feature extractor for machine learning. This needs to be compatible with .NET 6.0 and run cross-platform. The only real implementation I can find is in Accord.NET and this project appears to be dead.

Is there some equivalent in the ML.NET or SciSharp ecosystems?